# TextBox focus causes PivotItem to jump

Tags: textbox, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a simple layout of a Pivot containing two PivotItems, the first of which has a TextBox. I've set the margin of the first pivot item to zero because I want the contents to cover the whole width of the screen. The problem is that when the text box receives the focus, the pivot item (and its contents) jumps to the right by abount 10 pixels, which isn't a great experience.

I've tried calling UpdateLayout in the text box's GotFocus event, but it had no effect. Placing the text box in a Grid and setting a negative margin to that instead of the pivot item also didn't do anything.

Any thoughts as to how to fix this annoying visual hiccup? Thanks.

Comment: Did u apply a custom style to that text box??